# How can I cancel re-render view if view is in Route on React with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `Objects.tsx` and `Property.tsx` views.

In `Objects` I wrote `Switch` with Route `Property`.

```js
<Switch>
  <Route
    exact
    path="/objects/property"
    component={() => (
      <Property />
    )}
   />
</Switch>
```

In `Objects` by click on the input checkbox I am doing `history.push` with changed search params after it my `Property` view have been re-render. How I can do it without re-render `Property`?

Full `Objects` code:

```js
const Objects = () => {
  const [params, setParam] = useParams<{[key: string]: any}>({});
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(!!params.checked);

  const handleClickCheckbox = () => {
    setChecked(!checked);
    setParam('checked', !checked || '');
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleClickCheckbox} checked={checked} />
      </div>

      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/objects/property"
          component={() => (
            <Property />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the function component itself, you redefining it on every render.

```
const Objects = () => {
  ...
  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/objects/property"
          component={Property}
        />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I love you. Thank you very much!